# SSH - failed to release session

Tags: sshd

I have found the next line in the log on one of Ubuntu 18.04 server:

```
sshd[22190]: pam_systemd(sshd:session): Failed to release session: Interrupted system call
```

I can't find more description/solution to this. Any idea how to check what this means?